# Parse string by last 3 words and delete the last fourth one

Tags: php, string

I have two string breadcrumbs named:

> loriem_ipsum_wannadelete_bread_crumb_header

and

> dolor_sit_amet_sometext_wannadelete_bread_crumb_header

As you can see last three words are same which is "bread_crumb_header". Is it possible to remove the

> wannadelete_

part for all the breadcrumbs? And if so can you give me an idea?

My desired output is :

> loriem_ipsum_bread_crumb_header

and

> dolor_sit_amet_sometext_bread_crumb_header

Comment: You could also `explode` on the underscore, and rebuild the array.

Comment: yea, that's also another way of doing this. Thanks for the edit by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make use of [**`str_replace()`**](http://www.php.net/function.str-replace)

```
str_replace('wannadelete_','',$yourString);
```

Comment: Right, that works well. Guess I need a break

Answer (score 3):

Use **[str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)** in php

```
$str1 = 'loriem_ipsum_wannadelete_bread_crumb_header';
$str2 = 'dolor_sit_amet_sometext_wannadelete_bread_crumb_header';

$newStr1 = str_replace('wannadelete_','',$str1);
$newStr2 = str_replace('wannadelete_','',$str2);

echo $newStr1;
echo $newStr2;
```